# About two Zorn's Lemmas. ("Naive Set Theory and General Topology" by Masaaki Umehara and Shunsuke Ichiki.)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading "Naive Set Theory and General Topology" by Masaaki Umehara and Shunsuke Ichiki.
The authors call Propostion 2 Zorn's lemma.
But I think Proposition 1 is called Zorn's lemma in many books.

I tried to prove Proposition 2 using Proposition 1.
But I was not able to prove Proposition 2 using Proposition 1.
Please give me a hint.

I want to use Proposition 1 as a black box to prove Proposition 2.

Do I need to reread a proof of Proposition 1?

> Proposition 1:
> Suppose $X$ is a nonempty partially ordered set.
> Suppose any non-empty totally ordered subset of $X$ has an upper bound in $X$.
> Then, $X$ contains a maximal element.

> Proposition 2:
> Suppose $X$ is a nonempty partially ordered set.
> Suppose any non-empty totally ordered subset of $X$ has an upper bound in $X$.
> Suppose $x_0\in X$.
> Then, $X$ contains a maximal element $m$ such that $x_0\leq m$.

Comment: are these not identical? proposition 2 simply explains what a "maximal element" means.

Comment: Proposition 1 is usually called Zorn's lemma, although personally I prefer the slightly more obscure version: "Let $X$ be a partial order where every totally ordered subset has an upper bound. Then, $X$ has maximal elements". The idea for proving Proposition 2 using 1 is to apply proposition 1 to the poset $X'=\{x\in X\,:\, x_0\le x\}$.

Comment: @alexhroom No, it adds the condition to the thesis that not only there are maximal elements, but that for all $x_0\in X$ there is a maximal element larger or equal than $x_0$. For instance, an inductive poset can't be $\Bbb N$ plus a special element $m$ incomparable with $\Bbb N$: you have to have a maximal element larger than $5$.

Comment: @DumperDGarb Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: These are different propositions, so not sure why we have the downvotes. They are equivalent, and the proof is found in most text books.

Comment: @alexhroom Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @Porky Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: Corollary 7.1.6, Cunningham, A first course in set theory.

Comment: @Porky Thank you very much for your information.

Answer (score 1):

Dumper D Garb, Thank you very much for your answer!

Suppose $X$ is a nonempty partially ordered set.
Suppose any non-empty totally ordered subset of $X$ has an upper bound in $X$.
Suppose $x_0\in X$.
Let $X':=\{x\in X: x_0\leq x\}$.
Then, $X'$ is a nonempty partially ordered set.
And any non-empty totally ordered subset $Y$ of $X'$ is a non-empty totally ordered subset of $X$.
So, $Y$ has an upper bound $b$ in $X$.
Suppose $a\in Y$.
Since $Y\subset X'$, $a\in X'$.
So, $x_0\leq a\leq b$ holds.
So, $x_0\leq b$ holds.
So, $b\in X'$.
Therefore, $Y$ has an upper bound $b$ in $X'$.
By Proposition 1, $X'$ has a maximal element $m$.
Suppose that there exists $x\in X$ such that $m<x$.
Then, $x_0\leq m<x$ holds.
So, $x_0<x$ holds.
So, $x\in X'$.
So, $m$ is not a maximal element of $X'$.
This is a contradiction.
So, there is no element $x\in X$ such that $m<x$.
Therefore, $m$ is a maximal element of $X$.
Since $m\in X'$, $x_0\leq m$ holds.
So, Proposition 2 holds.